# Непрозрачность на половину блока

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, scss

можете подсказать как сделать такую прозрачность снизу вверх.
Пыталась с помощью background-gradient, но ничего не получилось.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FCFAFF;
  padding: 2rem;
}

section::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 100%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  width: 33.333%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Title</h1>

  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur попробуй блок наложить и дать ему свойство blur.